# I want to fill an ArrayList with the integers between 2 numbers

Tags: android

I am trying to store an ArrayList that contains all integers between two numbers that the user input in EditText's that I can access later.

I've tried mostly to go with an if statement. but can't really seem to pinpoint the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    EditText editText1;
    Integer kA;
    Integer kB;
    ArrayList<Integer> keyN;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        ArrayList<Integer> keyN = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void startCount (View view){

        kA = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        kB = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the part of the code that is not working? you state what you are trying to do, but not what the code you have provided is doing.

Comment: You probably don't want to create a new ArrayList in your onCreate again, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this snipped should achieve what you want.

```
for (int i = kA + 1; i < kB; i++) {
    keyN.add(i);
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(keyN.toString()); - doesn't work. And the app crashes when i click the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void startCount (View view){

 kA = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
 kB = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());

 // in between numbers
 for(int i = kA+1; i<kB; i++){
   keyN.add(i);
 }

 //output
 for(int i = 0; i<keyN.size(); i++){
  Log.d(keyN.get(i));
 }

}
```

Comment: System.out.println(keyN.toString());

Comment: @SerbanRadu `it crashes` with exception and stacktrace. Which ones?

Comment: Try to print the output inside the loop only. As you are using Android, I would recommend you to use Log.d('output'). I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @SerbanRadu Still getting an error then please share your stacktrace.